# How to query coredata with IN sql clause?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a `Device` Object, which has many `Types`.
In my app I need to query some devices with specific type or a group of types.
So the main function I use:

```
func get_ByDeviceType(_ type: Device.deviceType) -> [Device]? {
    let deviceFetch: NSFetchRequest<Device> = Device.fetchRequest()
    deviceFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "type == \(type.rawValue)")

    do {
        let device = try context.fetch(deviceFetch)
        return device
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Now when I try to get a group of `Devices` I tried this:

```
func get_ByDeviceTypes(_ types: [Device.deviceType]) -> [Device]? {
    var typesStr = ""
    var sep = ""
    for type in types {
        typesStr += sep + "\(type.rawValue)"
        sep = ","
    }
    let deviceFetch: NSFetchRequest<Device> = Device.fetchRequest()
    deviceFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "type in (%@)", typesStr)

    do {
        let device = try context.fetch(deviceFetch)
        return device
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}
```

But unfortunately it didn't work,

Is there a specific way to deal with this case. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `type` field of entity `Device` is of type `String`, use an `Array` of strings:

```
var typesStrings = [String]()
for type in types {
    typesStrings.append(type.rawValue)
} 
...
deviceFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "type in (%@)", typesStr)
```

---

If it is of type `Types`. simple take the given array right away:

```
deviceFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "type in (%@)", types)
```

Comment: Thanks it works, But I convert `Device.Type` from `Enum` to `Int`, Thank you